# make: *** [Makefile:86: obj/image_opencv.o] Error 127

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, yolo, darknet

I am trying to install yolo library in my windows 10 environment, After cloning the repository from  [This](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) link and after installing the cygwin, I did try to make the source but got following error.

**Error:**

```
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:86: obj/image_opencv.o] Error 127
```

**Complete log error**

```
dell@DESKTOP-95PQT6E /cygdrive/d
$ git clone https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet
Cloning into 'darknet'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5901, done.
remote: Total 5901 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 5901
Receiving objects: 100% (5901/5901), 6.16 MiB | 78.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3916/3916), done.

dell@DESKTOP-95PQT6E /cygdrive/d
$ pwd
/cygdrive/d

dell@DESKTOP-95PQT6E /cygdrive/d
$ cd darknet/

dell@DESKTOP-95PQT6E /cygdrive/d/darknet
$ make
mkdir -p obj
mkdir -p backup
mkdir -p results
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/utils.c -o obj/utils.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/cuda.c -o obj/cuda.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/deconvolutional_layer.c -o obj/deconvolutional_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/convolutional_layer.c -o obj/convolutional_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/list.c -o obj/list.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/image.c -o obj/image.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/activations.c -o obj/activations.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/im2col.c -o obj/im2col.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/col2im.c -o obj/col2im.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/blas.c -o obj/blas.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/crop_layer.c -o obj/crop_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/dropout_layer.c -o obj/dropout_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/maxpool_layer.c -o obj/maxpool_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/softmax_layer.c -o obj/softmax_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/data.c -o obj/data.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/matrix.c -o obj/matrix.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/network.c -o obj/network.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/connected_layer.c -o obj/connected_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/cost_layer.c -o obj/cost_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/parser.c -o obj/parser.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/option_list.c -o obj/option_list.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/detection_layer.c -o obj/detection_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/route_layer.c -o obj/route_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/upsample_layer.c -o obj/upsample_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/box.c -o obj/box.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/normalization_layer.c -o obj/normalization_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/avgpool_layer.c -o obj/avgpool_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/layer.c -o obj/layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/local_layer.c -o obj/local_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/shortcut_layer.c -o obj/shortcut_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/logistic_layer.c -o obj/logistic_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/activation_layer.c -o obj/activation_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/rnn_layer.c -o obj/rnn_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/gru_layer.c -o obj/gru_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/crnn_layer.c -o obj/crnn_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/demo.c -o obj/demo.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/batchnorm_layer.c -o obj/batchnorm_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/region_layer.c -o obj/region_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/reorg_layer.c -o obj/reorg_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/tree.c -o obj/tree.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/lstm_layer.c -o obj/lstm_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/l2norm_layer.c -o obj/l2norm_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/yolo_layer.c -o obj/yolo_layer.o
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/iseg_layer.c -o obj/iseg_layer.o
g++ -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/image_opencv.cpp -o obj/image_opencv.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:86: obj/image_opencv.o] Error 127
```

**Makefile contents**

```
GPU=1
CUDNN=0
OPENCV=0
OPENMP=0
DEBUG=0

ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
      -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
      -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] \
      -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]
#      -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] \ This one is deprecated?

# This is what I use, uncomment if you know your arch and want to specify
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52

VPATH=./src/:./examples
SLIB=libdarknet.so
ALIB=libdarknet.a
EXEC=darknet
OBJDIR=./obj/

CC=gcc
CPP=g++
NVCC=nvcc
AR=ar
ARFLAGS=rcs
OPTS=-Ofast
LDFLAGS= -lm -pthread
COMMON= -Iinclude/ -Isrc/
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC

ifeq ($(OPENMP), 1)
CFLAGS+= -fopenmp
endif

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
OPTS=-O0 -g
endif

CFLAGS+=$(OPTS)

ifeq ($(OPENCV), 1)
COMMON+= -DOPENCV
CFLAGS+= -DOPENCV
LDFLAGS+= `pkg-config --libs opencv` -lstdc++
COMMON+= `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
endif

ifeq ($(GPU), 1)
COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
CFLAGS+= -DGPU
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
endif

ifeq ($(CUDNN), 1)
COMMON+= -DCUDNN
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN
```

Can somebody guide me how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Since this error:

```
make: g++: Command not found
```

You need to install via cygwin a package named "g++". To do that you simply download the setup tool from cygwin official site then when it needs to install packages it will ask which packages do you want to install. In that list you find gcc-g++ and double click on skip button. Then continue the setup and try again.